# Invalid JSON but json looks to be valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I am grabbing a string and using $.parseJSON(string) but keep getting the following error:

```
uncaught exception: Invalid JSON: {"0":{"chartHtml":"&lt;p&gt; Slide 1&lt;/p&gt; ","presNote":"","chartOrderIndex":0},"1":{"chartHtml":"&lt;p&gt; Slide 2&lt;/p&gt; ","presNote":"","chartOrderIndex":1},"2":{"chartOrderIndex":2},"3":{"chartHtml":"&lt;p&gt; e 3&lt;/p&gt; ","presNote":"","chartOrderIndex":3},"4":{"chartHtml":"&lt;p&gt; Slide 4&lt;/p&gt; ","presNote":"","chartOrderIndex":4},"5":{"chartHtml":"&lt;p&gt; Slide 5&lt;/p&gt; ","presNote":"","chartOrderIndex":5},"6":{"chartOrderIndex":6}}
```

Firebug results during debug after running slideJson.d:

```
    >>> slideJson.d
"{"0":{"chartHtml":"&lt;p&gt; Slide 1&lt;/p&gt; ","presNote":"","chartOrderIndex":0},"1":{"chartHtml":"&lt;p&gt; Slide 2&lt;/p&gt; ","presNote":"","chartOrderIndex":1},"2":{"chartOrderIndex":2},"3":{"chartHtml":"&lt;p&gt; e 3&lt;/p&gt; ","presNote":"","chartOrderIndex":3},"4":{"chartHtml":"&lt;p&gt; Slide 4&lt;/p&gt; ","presNote":"","chartOrderIndex":4},"5":{"chartHtml":"&lt;p&gt; Slide 5&lt;/p&gt; ","presNote":"","chartOrderIndex":5},"6":{"chartOrderIndex":6}}"
```

Here is some of the call to deserialize the json:

```
function (slideJson) {
var slideObj, jsonStr;
if (slideJson.d) {
    slideObj = $.parseJSON(slideJson.d);
```

Ajax call to get the Json with content type:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Someurl',
    type: "POST",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) { somenamespace.loadSlides(data); }
});
```

Comment: I remember reading parseJSON required the keys AND values to be double-quoted.  But I can't find that in the documentation anymore... hmmm...

Comment: @John Strickler: Values are only quoted in JSON if they are string values.

Comment: This question is slightly misleading. The returned json is in fact valid json as mentioned by ShankarSangoli further below. There's no reason to use $.parseJSON.

Comment: `dataType: "json"` parses the JSON for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON string in question ended up containing `\n` and `\r` in the `chartHTML` property, which by default are generated by the CKeditor `.getData()` method. Since i was pasting the errors from firebug they were not visible and the JSON appeared to be valid which lead to my confusion.

Thanks to those who answered.

Answer (score 6):

Your JSON is valid, check http://jsonlint.com/

How about your content-type?  If you are using PHP set the following header:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: Agree.  I copied your JSON, replaced all quotes with backslash-quotes, entered it into the Chrome JS console, and ran JSON.parse on it and it came out fine.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to use `$.parseJSON` it is arelady well formed. Try to use it directly.

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WFYcb/)

Comment: Running console.log(typeof slideJson.d); during a debug session returns 'string' which leads me to believe it needs to be parsed?

Comment: If it is a string then yes you need to parse it.